# Sharepoint 2019 (Subscription) Variations messed up?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, 2019, variations, mui

After some users complained that they don't see the most recent version of the landing page, I investigated the issue and noticed that the user does have indeed a different (outdated) version of the page compared to me.
As it turns out, it is because his language is set to English while mine is set to German.
So as there were some changes to the variation settings (was enabled and disabled again) a while a go I thought it is a not updated page, but further investigation confused me.

- On /Variation%20Labels/allitems.aspx there are no elements
- /_layouts/15/muisetng.aspx does have the alternative language English enabled (LP installed)
- On /_layouts/15/exporttranslations.aspx I can export German and English
- On /_layouts/15/VariationLabels.aspx are no elements
  /_layouts/15/VariationLogs.aspx only gives an error (in case it's relevant -> ULS)

```
12/17/2023 22:58:24.30  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x14F8)                       0x0DC8  SharePoint Foundation           Timer                           cb5oc   Medium      [NoLockTypeDBPartitioning]: NoLockTypeDBPartitioningFlight is DISABLED! Reverting to old behavior. [isNoLockTypeDBPartitioningFlightEnabled = False]    67bff8a0-3913-5021-1bd1-b96a786150cc
12/17/2023 22:58:24.30  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x14F8)                       0x0DC8  SharePoint Foundation           Timer                           cb5oc   Medium      [NoLockTypeDBPartitioning]: NoLockTypeDBPartitioningFlight is DISABLED! Reverting to old behavior. [isNoLockTypeDBPartitioningFlightEnabled = False]    67bff8a0-3913-5021-1bd1-b96a786150cc
12/17/2023 22:58:24.30  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x14F8)                       0x0DC8  SharePoint Foundation           Timer                           cb5oc   Medium      [NoLockTypeDBPartitioning]: NoLockTypeDBPartitioningFlight is DISABLED! Reverting to old behavior. [isNoLockTypeDBPartitioningFlightEnabled = False]    67bff8a0-3913-5021-1bd1-b96a786150cc
12/17/2023 22:58:24.30  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x14F8)                       0x0DC8  SharePoint Foundation           Timer                           cb5oc   Medium      [NoLockTypeDBPartitioning]: NoLockTypeDBPartitioningFlight is DISABLED! Reverting to old behavior. [isNoLockTypeDBPartitioningFlightEnabled = False]    67bff8a0-3913-5021-1bd1-b96a786150cc
12/17/2023 22:58:24.30  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x14F8)                       0x0DC8  SharePoint Foundation           Database                        a08yc   High        Database with Id 43d414f4-c262-4929-9d24-eeccf181bd1b was not found in database collection. Returning null. 67bff8a0-3913-5021-1bd1-b96a786150cc
12/17/2023 22:58:24.30  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x14F8)                       0x0DC8  SharePoint Foundation           Database                        bggfq   Medium      UsageLoggedSqlSession: Before executing command against SharePoint_Config. Command is dbo.proc_AddTimerJobHistory   67bff8a0-3913-5021-1bd1-b96a786150cc
12/17/2023 22:58:24.30  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x14F8)                       0x0DC8  SharePoint Foundation           Timer                           an9i8   Medium      Completed processing of timer job [job-microserviceworkitem-queue] with lock type [None] against target instance [43d414f4-c262-4929-9d24-eeccf181bd1b] [SPServer Name=SRV21]. Start time: [12/17/2023 21:58:24]. Duration: [00:00:00]. Status result: [Succeeded]. Status ressage (if any): [].    67bff8a0-3913-5021-1bd1-b96a786150cc
12/17/2023 22:58:24.30  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x14F8)                       0x0DC8  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope: (Timer Job job-microserviceworkitem-queue) Ausführungszeit=13.2402; CPU Milliseconds=3; SQL-Abfrageanzahl=29; Parent=None  67bff8a0-3913-5021-1bd1-b96a786150cc
```

Anyone ever had a similar issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See: https://debug.to/2497/sharepoint-2019-variations

As per MSFT *"This service will become unavailable and unsupported entirely by the end of July 2022."*

1. Make sure you're using a site template that supports Variations.
2. Check if the correct Language Pack is installed and enabled.
3. If there are no elements in the Variation Labels pages, there might be a problem.
4. Check if the timer jobs are working and look for error messages in the logs. There might be a database issue.